# JAXB not generating XML as per the Annotations (JDK 1.7)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;



    public class JavaToXMLDemo {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Employee object = new Employee();
    object.setCode("CA");
    object.setName("Cath");
    object.setSalary(300);
    object.setProperties(new PropertiesMap());
    m.marshal(object, System.out);

  }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Employee {
  private String code;

  @XmlElement(name = "Name")
  private String name;

  private int salary;

  @XmlElement(name = "Properties")
  protected PropertiesMap params;

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public PropertiesMap getProperties() {
      return params;
  }

  public void setProperties(PropertiesMap value) {
      this.params = value;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }

  public void setSalary(int population) {
    this.salary = population;
  }
}


  @XmlRootElement(name="Properties")
  class PropertiesMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>
  {

  }
```

The above code generates the below XML with JDK 1.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Employee>
    <code>CA</code>
    <Name>Cath</Name>
    <salary>300</salary>
    <Properties/>
</Employee>
```

and this on JDK 1.7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Employee>
    <code>CA</code>
    <Name>Cath</Name>
    <salary>300</salary>
    <params/>
</Employee>
```

Why does the Marshaller behave differently?

Comment: I believe this is not because of the JDK version but because different JAXB versions are bundled with JDKs.
JDK 1.7 version seems correct to me, the root element name should be used as a root element or in element references (I guess). What happens when you add `@XmlElementRef` annotation to your property?

Comment: @lexicore - you are right, it is due to the different JAXB versions bundled with JDKs. The actual culprit is my `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` . I have created a new question with details on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942081/xmladapter-not-working-correctly-with-newer-version-of-jaxb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@XmlElementWrapper` instead of `@XmlElement` for your Properties map.

See http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html use case #2.

Comment: That solved it. I'm using xjc to generate the JAXB annotated classes. So I have created a new question for the actual problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942081/xmladapter-not-working-correctly-with-newer-version-of-jaxb