# XmlAdapter not working correctly with newer version of JAXB

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm executing a Maven Project with the below source

```
package com.coderplus.jaxb;

import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PropertiesMapAdapter.class)
public class PropertiesMap<K,V> extends HashMap<String,String>
{

}
```

..

```
package com.coderplus.jaxb;

import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;


public class PropertiesMapAdapter extends
        XmlAdapter<Properties, PropertiesMap<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public PropertiesMap<String, String> unmarshal(Properties properties)
            throws Exception {
        PropertiesMap<String, String> retVal = new PropertiesMap<String, String>();
        if (null != properties) {
            for (Property param : properties.getProperty()) {
                retVal.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties marshal(PropertiesMap<String, String> propertiesMap)
            throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        if (propertiesMap != null) {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {
                Property param = new Property();
                param.setName(entry.getKey());
                param.setValue(entry.getValue());
                properties.getProperty().add(param);
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

..

```
package com.coderplus.jaxb;  
import javax.xml.bind.*;


public class Demo {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Root root = new Root();
        PropertiesMap map = new PropertiesMap();
        map.put("hello", "World");
        map.put("name", "value");
        root.setProperties(map);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

...

Schema in src/main/resources

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="Properties">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Property" type="Property" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Property">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="Root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Properties" type="Properties" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Binding file in src/main/resources

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="map.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Properties']">
            <jaxb:property>
                <jaxb:baseType name="com.coderplus.jaxb.PropertiesMap&lt;String,String&gt;" />
            </jaxb:property>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

and finally the pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com.coderplus.jaxb</generatePackage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Demo Class produces the below output when I execute it using JDK 1.6

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="hello">World</Property>
        <Property name="name">value</Property>
    </Properties>
</Root>
```

but for some reason, it generates the below with JDK 1.7 and up (newer JAXB?)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <properties>
        <entry>
            <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">hello</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">World</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">name</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">value</value>
        </entry>
    </properties>
</Root>
```

How can I get it working on JDK 1.7 or the newer version of JAXB?

**Some More Info:**

The maven-jaxb2-plugin generates the below class along with others

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "properties"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "Properties", required = true, type = Properties.class)
    protected PropertiesMap<String, String> properties;

    public PropertiesMap<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(PropertiesMap<String, String> value) {
        this.properties = value;
    }

}
```

If I manually go in and add the annotation `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PropertiesMapAdapter.class)` like in the code below, then it works

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "properties"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "Properties", required = true, type = Properties.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PropertiesMapAdapter.class)
    protected PropertiesMap<String, String> properties;

    public PropertiesMap<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(PropertiesMap<String, String> value) {
        this.properties = value;
    }

}
```

How can I make the maven-jaxb2-plugin to add the `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` automatically? In case it would help, this link has the [zipped Maven Project](http://goo.gl/xxUVhC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the [xjc:javaType](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#javaType) customization.

```
<xjc:javaType name="org.acme.foo.PropertiesMap"
 adapter="org.acme.foo.PropertiesMapAdapter"/>
```

Comment: I had tried that, but if gives a "compiler was unable to honor this conversion customization..." error.Seems like it will only work with simpleTypes?

Comment: Hm, maybe. Not sure. Ok, now the last and most powerful. Annotate plugin can annotate anything with anything for you: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin

Comment: I have been working on the annotate plugin for a couple of days and finally got it to work today. It seems that annotate doesn't work for complex XPaths with ref attributes(at least in my case). Amended the schema to get this sorted. Thank a lot :-)

Comment: Please file an issue on github with the case that does not work.

Comment: sure, will create a dummy example and file a case. Thanks again :)

Comment: @coderplus Please send me a PR with your test case: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/tests